# How to get text on one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-break

I am trying to get the text "yes please" on one line. I want it aligned exactly like that. However it is displaying on two lines.

```html
<section class="contactus">
  <div class="contactustitle">
    <h1>Where happy to hear from you</h1>
    <ion-icon style="width: 100%;" name="remove-outline"></ion-icon>

  </div>
  <div class="contactusinput" style="width: 60%">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Name</p> <input style="width: 70%;" placeholder="Your name" type="text"> </div>
    <div class="email">
      <p>Email</p> <input type="text" placeholder="Email" style="width: 70%;"> </div>
    <div class="refer">
      <p>How did you find us? </p> <input type="text" placeholder="Your erfferer" style="width: 70%;"> </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 42%;">
      <p>Newsletter?</p>
      <div style="display: inline-flex;  border: 1px solid red;"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="">yes, please</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>drop us a line</p> <input type="textarea" placeholder="Your message" style="width: 70%; height: 100px;" style=""> </div>
    <div style=" display: flex; justify-content: center;"><button style="width: 20%; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #e67e22; border-radius: 200px; background-color: #e67e22; color: #ffff; font-weight: 300;">Send it!</button></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from all CSS and inline styles one could think of, in this particular situation (i.e. just two short words) the easiest way to achieve that is to put a "non-breaking space" HTML entity between the words "yes" and "please" instead of the normal space. So instead of "yes, please" your text (in the code) would be `yes,&nbsp;please`

Comment: that seemed to remove the checkbox?

Comment: no, that's not possible - you must have done something else to cause that. Or else, the container ended up being too narrow and something is cut off at the side (check with the browser tools)

Comment: Hmm, no, that was the only thing I touched?

Comment: sorry, but that really isn't possible